# Read a Weidmuller File and get data from it

Tags: python, python-3.11

I have a file, created with the program "[M-Print Pro, for Weidmuller](https://www.weidmuller.it/it/prodotti/workplace_accessories/software/m_print_pro.jsp)". It has the file extension ".mpc" The file description given by the program is "Files with M-Print PRO contents"

This is an example of what it looks like via the program:

[image]

Now, I tried to look for a Python library to read the file, but unfortunately I didn't find any, since that kind of extension is commonly used for Musepack audio.

At this point, I simply tried opening it with:

```
r = open("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/E3611310/CABLAGGIO.mpc", "r")
print(r.read())
```

What I get is the following error:

```
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 188: character maps to <undefined>
```

I tried adding `encoding="utf8"`, but still I get an error::

```
File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 10: invalid start byte
```

What I'm trying to do are two, namely being able to read and recover the data of this type of file, and being able to create a similar file with new data.

Do you have any ideas on how I could solve it? Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `.mpc` is a proprietary file format of that company. I wasn't able to find any documentation or specifications about that file format.

Due to your problem I would suggest that the `.mpc` file format isn't saved as charcters with `utf-8` encoding (maybe no encoding at all..., could be their own encoding or bytewise).
As always when proprietary file formats are involved I the only suggestions I can give you are:

1. If you have a lot of time **you need to manually decode the file format** (Unfortunately I don't think that is possible...). **I would not recommend that,** as the company can literally change it completely at any time!
2. S**witch to a standardized file format (my suggestion!)**. However this is not alwys possible (I don't know if there is one in your specific case)
3. **Use the proprietary software** which is intended to work with the proprietary file format (obviously that's the reason for companies to use proprietary file formats...)